# Firebase Emulator on Bitbucket Pipeline

Tags: firebase, bitbucket-pipelines, firebase-tools

I'm trying to run Firebase Emulator on Bitbucket Pipeline. It fails because "java is not installed".

[image]

How can I "install java" on a Bitbucket Pipeline. Or is there another way to get it to work?

My step currently looks like this:

```
- step: &test-rules
        name: 'Test Firestore Rules (DEV)'
        image: node:16.13.2
        script:
          - npm ci --prefix firebase-test
          - npm install -g firebase-tools
          - npm run test --prefix firebase-test
```

`npm run test` runs this script:

```
firebase emulators:exec --only firestore "mocha --exit"
```

Comment: ANy updates or help on this would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I've just faced this error and managed to solve it. Basically what you need is setting a Docker image that has both, Node and Java, Node for your code and Java for the emulator.

So I've used the image [timbru31/java-node](https://hub.docker.com/r/timbru31/java-node) available in DockerHub. For me it worked with the version java-node:11-jre-14, but in your case you must want to use the version java-node:11-jdk-16 which contains Node 16 and JDK 11 (or the one you prefer, maybe with newer versions of java and node).

Here's an example:

```
- step: &test-rules
        name: 'Test Firestore Rules (DEV)'
        image: timbru31/java-node:11-jdk-16
        script:
          - npm ci --prefix firebase-test
          - npm install -g firebase-tools
          - npm run test --prefix firebase-test
```